# Making code run faster (re-ordering rows corresponding to points in plane)

Tags: r

I am working with a dataset that gives the coordinates of a large amount of points. Each row corresponds to a point and the columns give the x-coordinate and the y-coordinate of the point. I am trying to re-order the rows such that, if point X is closest to point Y, then row X is closest to row Y.

I have written the following code but R takes ages to run it so I was wondering if you could help me write a faster code:

```
# first I create a function that calculates the distance between the points associated with row a and row b:
distance = function(a,b) {
  u <- c(d[a,5], d[a,6]) ### d is the data frame whose rows I am re-ordering; its 5th column gives the x-coordinate, the 6th its y-coordinate
  v <- c(d[b,5], d[b,6])
  dist <- sqrt((u[1]-v[1])^2 + (u[2] - v[2])^2)
  return(dist)
}

h <- rep(0, nrow(d)) 
l <- rep(0, nrow(d)) ### I will put in this variable the correct order of the rows numbers
l[1] <- 1 ### I start with row 1

 for(i in 1:nrow(d)) {
  if(i == 1) {  ### I calculate the distance between the first point and all the other points
     for(j in 1:length(h)) {
    h[j] <- distance(1,j)
    }
   }
  else {
    for(j in 1:length(h)) { ### I calculate the distance between the point considered (l[i-1]) and all the other points
    h[j] <- distance(l[i-1],j)
    }
  }
  k <- h[!is.nan(h)] ### for some reasons I get NaN (not sure why) and that makes the min() function below output nothing interesting 
  l[i+1] <- which(h == min(k[-c(i,l[1:i])])) ### I get the row number who is closest to the point considered (e.g. the smallest value in h) that is not the row itself or rows already considered
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: This question might be better asked on [Code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

This is a completely different solution, but you're calculating distance and trying to "cluster" your columns, so it might be useful.

```
set.seed(200)
data <- data.frame(x = sample(1:100, 5),
               y = sample(1:200, 5))

hc <- hclust(dist(data))
data2 <- data[hc$order,]
```

`dist` calculates euclidean distance between all the rows of data. Then `hclust` uses that distance to clusterize the points. I'm just using the default methods, but you can change them too. Then, you can use the order given by hclust to reorganize your data. This should be quite fast.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I get the following error message: Error in hclust(dist(d[, 5:6])) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 11)

Comment: Are both columns numeric and have no missing values? You can post a reproducible example for us to test using `dput(head(d))`